# UnboundLocalError variable not recognized

Tags: python, local-variables

I am getting an error that says: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'words' referenced before assignment` but I am unsure on why. The following is my code:

```
def hasher(fname):
    try:
        with open(fname, 'r') as f:
            words = re.split('(["\'@&,;:\(\)\s+\*\?\.]|\w+)', f.read().lower())
    except:
        print 'Out'

    while '' in words:
        words.remove('')
```

But I'm getting the error when I try to reference words in the while statement and I'm not sure on why. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: In case if an exception occurs then `words` will not be defined, and you'll get error on this line `while '' in words:`

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a default value,

```
def hasher(fname):
    words = []
    try:
        with open(fname, 'r') as f:
            words = re.split('(["\'@&,;:\(\)\s+\*\?\.]|\w+)', f.read().lower())
    except:
        print 'Out'

    while '' in words:
        words.remove('')

    return words
```